# Get All permuation combination of a list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list like this.

```
[[((5, 10), 0), ((49, 54), 0)],[((11, 16), 1), ((55, 60), 1)],[((27, 33), 2), ((61, 67), 2)],[((17, 26), 3), ((34, 43), 3), ((68, 77), 3)],[((83, 85), 4)]]
```

my desired output is . Request you to help me on this using python.

```
[(5, 10),(11, 16),(27, 33),(17,26),(83, 85)]
[(5, 10),(55, 60),(27, 33),(17,26),(83, 85)]
[(5, 10),(55, 60),(61, 67),(17,26),(83, 85)]

[(5, 10),(11, 16),(61,67),(17,26),(83, 85)]


[(5, 10),(11, 16),(27, 33),(34,43),(83, 85)]
[(5, 10),(55, 60),(27, 33),(34,43),(83, 85)]
[(5, 10),(55, 60),(61, 67),(34,43),(83, 85)]

[(5, 10),(11, 16),(61,67),(34,43),(83, 85)]

[(5, 10),(11, 16),(27, 33),(68, 77),(83, 85)]
[(5, 10),(55, 60),(27, 33),(68, 77),(83, 85)]
[(5, 10),(55, 60),(61, 67),(68, 77),(83, 85)]

[(5, 10),(11, 16),(61,67),(68, 77),(83, 85)]

[(49, 54),(11, 16),(27, 33),(17,26),(83, 85)]
[(49, 54),(55, 60),(27, 33),(17,26),(83, 85)]
[(49, 54),(55, 60),(61, 67),(17,26),(83, 85)]

[(49, 54),(11, 16),(61,67),(17,26),(83, 85)]


[(49, 54),(11, 16),(27, 33),(34,43),(83, 85)]
[(49, 54),(55, 60),(27, 33),(34,43),(83, 85)]
[(49, 54),(55, 60),(61, 67),(34,43),(83, 85)]

[(49, 54),(11, 16),(61,67),(34,43),(83, 85)]

[(49, 54),(11, 16),(27, 33),(68, 77),(83, 85)]
[(49, 54),(55, 60),(27, 33),(68, 77),(83, 85)]
[(49, 54),(55, 60),(61, 67),(68, 77),(83, 85)]

[(49, 54),(11, 16),(61,67),(68, 77),(83, 85)]
```

Comment: permutation or combination?

Comment: It called Cartesian product. There's function [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which you can use in combination with simple list comprehension: `[[i[0] for i in p] for p in product(*l)]`

Comment: It is not clear what does the second index of each sublist is used for, but anyway, you may want to read https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations and use

Comment: @OlvinRoght what is *l in your statment ,it is giving error. sorry for my poor understanding

Comment: @vikassharma, `l` is name of variable which contains source list.